# Soap Action not parsed as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, soap, savon

For some reason, if I try:

```
response = client.request 'Security_Authenticate' do
```

It doesn't work, the response returns any random fault message. 
However, if I specify the SOAP Action URL:

```
response = client.request 'http://webservices.xxx.com/whatever' do
```

it works perfectly.

Is this a Savon issue parsing the wsdl?

**RESOLVED: I had to use lowercase for the action!**

Comment: What is the "randomm fault message"? Usually software doesn't send random messages :-). It also can't hurt to post some code or some parts of the log to reproduce your problem.

Comment: The fault message is about a header presentation error (whichs is not true... that's why I called it 'random')... LOOK AT MY EDIT.